# Biztalk 2006r2 Commerce Server Adapter

Tags: biztalk, commerceserver2007, microsoft-commerce-server

I am trying to query Commerce Server 2007 using the Biztalk Adapter.

I am using the OrdersAdapter and trying to query for all orders with a specific line item on them.

The message xml is

```
<CommerceServerOrdersQuery>
 <CLAUSE OPER="equal" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/CommerceServer/2004/02/Expressions">
  <PROPERTY ID="LineItem.ProductId" MULTIVAL="false" TYPE="String" />
  <IMMED-VAL TYPE="String">
   <VALUE>xxx</VALUE>
  </IMMED-VAL>
 </CLAUSE>
</CommerceServerOrdersQuery>
```

If I query by PurchaseOrder.OrderStatus or some property on the purchase order, it works fine.  however if i try to use the line item property as the criteria it fails with this error.

> The 'ProductId' property is not a
>   searchable property of entity
>   'PurchaseOrder'.  Searchable
>   properties can be discovered by
>   inspecting the DataSet returned by the
>   GetSearchableProperties method.

I did query the GetSearchableProperties service specified and it did indeed say that LineItem.ProductId is a searchable property.  Furthermore if I do this query with the .NET API, i can see it producing the exact xml i am using and it works. The problem comes when using the BTS Adapter.

[The documentation for this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa545797.aspx) is pretty thin with no in depth examples, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.